# Erro PATH Android Ionic Cordova

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript, apache-cordova

Bom, tenho instalado o ionic na nova versão, e android studio normalmente e até esses dias funcionava. Agora quando fui dar build, me retornou esses dois erros:

```
Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Então verifiquei se minhas variáveis de ambiente estavam ok, e dando echo $ANDROID_HOME, eu obtenho '/home/willian/Android/Sdk
'. Está exatamente como estava quando funcionava, porém agora não encontra o sdk.

Uso linux mint cinnamon. Alguém pode me dar uma mão sobre isso.
Obs: Vi várias perguntas relacionadas, mas nenhuma delas corrigiu esse problema. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Poderia alterar a pergunta colocando o resultado deste comando: cat /etc/environment?

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque o caminho para o Android Sdk não está definido corretamente. Verifique o caminho correto para o Sdk, tools, platform-tools, emulator and Android build-tools.

> Por favor, perceba que a configuração recomendada para o Ionic mudou um pouco. Agora a notação recomendada é a seguinte:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/username/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/username/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
```

No Linux ou Mac OS X configure o path no arquivo ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile :

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools
```

No final, depois de salvar a configuração, não esqueça de dar o comando:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

ou em outros casos

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Para usuários Windows, verifiquem as variáveis globais.

Comment: Se eu uso ***ANDROID_SDK_ROOT*** o build da erro pedindo ANDROID_HOME. La no site quando diz que atualizou as variáveis, é somente o caminho e não nome. Quando eu exporto ANDROID_HOME na mesma hora que vou fazer o build, ele funciona .

Comment: Sim o foco é no path, a nova notação é apenas uma recomendação. Conforme a documentação: [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android). Se a resposta estiver correta, por favor marque-a como tal.

Comment: Porém não está correta. O que você pediu pra fazer não adiantou em nada. O erro só é corrigido quando executo com SUDO SU, do mesma maneira que está hoje.

Comment: O ideal é que não se use sudo su para isto. O que imagino que você pode não ter percebido de diferente é que tem: `/home/username/Android/Sdk` o path inteiro, não apenas o final `/Android/Sdk`.